# Why does Conv2DTranspose outputs checkerboarded images if using matched kernel sizes and strides?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I've read multiple times the famous distill paper concernging why Conv2DTranspose results in checkerboard artefacts. https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/

I understand from it, however, that if both the kernel size and the strides are matched, there shouldn't be any issue. I'm downsampling using `Conv2D` with `kernel=(2,2)` and `strides=(2,2)`. And I'm upsampling using `Conv2DTranspose` with the exact same values. However if I visualize the output of the `Conv2DTranspose` layers they're extremely checkerboaded. Nothing that the next conv layer can't fix but... Why is that? By the way, I don't see artefacts in the final output (also, I'm segmenting so you don't see small intensity noise in the final quasi-binary mask).

What's the exact definition of `Conv2DTranspose` anyway? I'd expect the output of such a layer to be non "grid-like" when using matched kernel and strides (as shown in the examples in the distill link above), but in the documentation there's no exact mathematical definition of what it's doing. Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `Conv2Transpose` mathematical operation is the exact opposite of the `Convolution`. Note that the usage of `Deconvolution` or other terms is mathematically incorrect.

[image]

This is the perfect example to illustrate, since it uses exactly a stride of two. You can see how the initial image size is 2x2, the white squares are 0 padding, and the final output tensor dimension is 4x4.

Although not in use anymore, http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html#transposed-convolution-arithmetic the theano documentation explains beautifully the mathematics behind `Conv2DTranspose`. You should check the documentation to better understand.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term 'exact inverse' since convolutions and indeed matrix multiplication often aren't invertible functions. Perhaps 'opposite' is a better term?

Comment: Indeed, opposite is a more suitable word.

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect the correct mathematical term.

Comment: I still don't get one thing... What is the kernel doing here? I'd expect that you take the value of 1 pixel in input and get a 3x3 square of values in output (pixel value times each kernel values). Instead in this link it show that you get 1 pixel in input and get 1 pixel in output and the others are left at zero (e.g.: relationship 10, non-unit stride)